# What does "fraginat" (maybe "freginat") mean?

Tags: alimentation

This is a culinary term I know. I have a recipe for Fraginat de Boeuf, but it doesn't explain what fraginat means. A Google search returns pages in French, but none in English and no online dictionary can translate it.

Sometimes freginat seems to be used in a similar way.

Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freginat is the name of a dish originated from the Pyrénées (mountains at the border with Spain). It was originally prepared with wild boar but pork or beef are more common now, while boar is used for special occasions. Meat is cooked for a long time with tomatoes and bacon and vinegar is added at the end, sometimes with honey for a more sweet and sour taste. It is served with white beans.

The name "freginat" originates from "fregida", which means "fricassee" in Occitan (regional language spoken in southern France).

Comment: More precisely from Aude (although other areas claim it as well...) which is not entirely a mountain area.

Comment: Upvoted your answer  but I suggest you replace "original" by "regional language spoken". Original doesn't mean anything in this context. Occitan originates in Latin and is not only spoken in the south of France ...  By the way, Occitan *fregida* means "frit", (verb is *fregir*).

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9ginat), **fraginat** is [the occitan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan) for [fricassée](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fricass%C3%A9e/35234). More details on the [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freginat)

Comment: Your answer is misleading since it implies that fréginat is another name for fricassée which it isn't. Fricassée is a very generic term and  fréginat is a very specific dish from the south west of France. See @SteffX for details.

Comment: Good point, I deleted the definition of Fricassée.